# Deep links do not work in Samsung native apps

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, galaxy

Samsung Galaxy S6, Android Marshmallow 6.0. Developing with Unity.

## Samsung's apps

Deep links *https://* do **not** work, but *intent://* **do** work in:

- Internet app
- Memo app

## Google's apps

Both *https://* and *intent://* **do** work in:

- Google Chrome app
- Gmail app

Is there something about Samsung custom apps?

## Code

assetlinks.json

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.xxx.app",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["4E:CC:14:62:B3:1D:13..."]
  }
}]
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- REPLACE  com.companyname.projectname to your app bundle ID-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.xxx.app" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="1" />
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name="causallink.assets.DeepLinkBridge" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="v.xxx.com" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

P.S. I have googled and found **a lot** of SO posts, but none of them I found actually helpful.

Comment: maybe you should consider try to use this library.. [Deeplink Dispatch](https://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch)..

Comment: Thank you for the link. However at first I would really like to understand why it actually happens.

Comment: @igorpavlov did you figure out why this was happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "https://" deep links you refer to are using Android's App Links mechanism for opening apps (check this link for a good overview: https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-deep-linking-android-app-links/).

The "intent://" deep links are using Chrome Intents (check: https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-deep-linking-on-android-chrome-intents/).

The Samsung apps you mention simply don't support App Links - support is spotty for App Links generally. The safest path is to support both URI Scheme linking/Chrome intents and App Links, as you will find different apps that support one but not the other - and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this multiple config.. hope its work

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:host="v.xxx.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/yourpath"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="www.v.xxx.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/yourpath"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="*.v.xxx.com"
                android:scheme=""
                android:path="/yourpath/" />
            <data
                android:path=""
                android:pathPrefix="/*"
                android:pathPattern="\?"
                android:pathPattern="put your regex" />

</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. Could you please explain why this config you think will work? Doesn't Samsung like just this: android:host="v.xxx.com" for some reason?